# How can I replace os.system output with replace method?

Tags: python, replace, os.system

```
def folderFinder():
   import os
   os.chdir("C:\\")
   command = "dir *.docx /s | findstr Directory"
   os.system(command).replace("Directory of ","")
```

The result that comes out of here is the "Directory of" text at the beginning, I am trying to remove this text with the replace method so that only the file names remain, but it works directly and I cannot do the replacement I want. How can fix this problem(i am new at python)

Comment: What is the output you get and what is the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.system()` simply prints its results to the console. If you want the strings to be passed back to Python, you need to use `subprocess` (or one of the wrappers which ends up calling `subprocess` anyway eventually, like `os.popen`).

```py
import subprocess

def folderFinder():
   output = subprocess.check_output("dir *.docx /s", shell=True, text=True, cwd="C:\\")
   for line in output.splitlines():
        if "Directory" in line and "Directory of " not in line:
            print(line)
```

Notice how the `cwd=` keyword avoids having to permanently change the working directory of the current Python process.

I factored out the `findstr Directory` too; it usually makes sense to run as little code as possible in a subprocess.

`text=True` requires Python 3.7 or newer; in some older versions, it was misleadingly called `universal_newlines=True`.

If your target is simply to find files matching `*.docx` in subdirectories, using a subprocess is arcane and inefficient; just do

```py
import glob

def folderFinder():
    return glob.glob(r"C:\**\*.docx", recursive=True)
```

Comment: I ran the code containing glob, it didn't give an error but it give not output

Comment: i changed the return with print and got the result as i wanted thanks